# gcc 4.9 debug version build on Solaris Sparc

Tags: gcc, solaris, ld, libstdc++, sparc

I am trying to build a debug version of gcc 4.9.2 on Solaris 10 sparc. I've configured as (mostly following this link: https://lucamerello.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/solaris-10-how-to-build-and-install-gcc-4/):

```
../configure --build=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --program-suffix=-4.9.2 --enable-libstdcxx-debug 
               --with-gmp=/home/gcc-4.9.2/gmp-6.0.0a 
               --with-mpfr=/home/gcc-4.9.2/mpfr-3.1.2 
               --with-mpc=/home/gcc-4.9.2/mpc-1.0.2 
               --without-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as 
               --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld 
               --enable-shared 
               --disable-nls 
               --enable-languages=c,c++
               --prefix=/home/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2 
               --with-stage1-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath=/home/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2/lib/math,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" 
               --with-boot-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath=/home/gcc-4.9.2/gcc-4.9.2/lib/math,-rpath=/usr/local/lib -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"
```

When it tries to build libstdc++, I am getting this error:

ld: fatal: unwind table: file .libs/compatibility.o: section .eh_frame: bad cie version 0: offset 0x7f000018

The last command (before the error) is:

libtool: link:  /home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -shared-libgcc -B/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/./gcc -nostdinc++ -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/src -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -B/home/gcc-4.9.2/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/home/gcc-4.9.2/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /home/gcc-4.9.2/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /home/gcc-4.9.2/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -shared -nostdlib  /usr/lib/crti.o /usr/ccs/lib/values-Xa.o /home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/./gcc/crtbegin.o  .libs/compatibility.o .libs/compatibility-debug_list.o .libs/compatibility-debug_list-2.o .libs/compatibility-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-thread-c++0x.o .libs/compatibility-chrono.o .libs/compatibility-condvar.o  -Wl,-z -Wl,allextract ../../libsupc++/.libs/libsupc++convenience.a ../../src/debug/c++98/.libs/libc++98convenience.a ../../src/debug/c++11/.libs/libc++11convenience.a -Wl,-z -Wl,defaultextract  -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/src -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -lm -lposix4 -L/home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/./gcc -L/usr/ccs/lib -lgcc_s -lc -lgcc_s -lc /home/gcc-4.9.2/src/objdir/./gcc/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o  -Wl,-M -Wl,libstdc++-symbols.ver-sun   -Wl,-h -Wl,libstdc++.so.6 -o .libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.20

Has anybody experience similar problem?

Looks like it has patch (139574/139555). Result of command 
showrev -p | egrep '139574|139555':

Patch: 141444-09 Obsoletes: 119143-02, 120807-01, 122754-01, 123402-01, 124924-01, 125915-01, 126266-01, 126421-02, 128004-01, 128304-04, 128306-05, 128328-01, 128334-01, 128491-01, 137021-03, 137121-06, 137129-06, 137141-01, 137289-02, 137292-01, 138044-02, 138083-01, 138104-01, 138130-01, 138174-04, 138255-03, 138269-02, 138392-01, 138625-02, 138629-01, 139386-02, 139462-02, 139464-01, 139490-01, 139881-01, 139928-03, 139956-01, 139964-03, 139973-01, 139974-03, 139977-07, 139982-04, 139985-02, 139991-03, 139993-03, 139996-02, 140150-01, 140338-01, 140408-01, 140589-02, 140916-02, 140919-04, 141028-01, 141057-01, 141414-10, 141494-01, 141510-03, 141520-01, 141524-03, 141530-01, 141538-01, 141540-01, 141546-01, 141554-01, 141556-01, 141560-02, 141690-02, 141692-01, 141694-02, 141715-03, 141721-03, 141729-01, 141731-01, 141733-04, 141736-05, 141742-04, 141743-04, 141767-01, 141770-01, 141771-01, 141775-01, 141777-01, 141781-02, 141892-01, 141894-01, 141902-02, 141908-01, 141918-01, 141920-03, 141934-01, 142004-01, 142013-01, 142051-01, 142056-02, 142246-01, 142284-01, 142479-01, 142483-01, 142489-01 Requires: 118833-36, 118918-24, 119042-09, 119254-41, 119578-30, 120011-14, 120900-04, 121133-02, 121901-01, 121921-02, 125503-02, 126540-02, 126897-02, 127127-11, 127755-01, 137137-09, 139555-08, 142292-01 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWpl5v, SUNWixgbe, SUNWpiclu, SUNWhea, SUNWrds, SUNWnfsskr, SUNWkvm, SUNWibsdpib, SUNWpool, SUNWxcu4, SUNWhermon, SUNWiscsitgtu, SUNWfmd, SUNWopenssl-commands, SUNWopenssl-include, SUNWmdbr, SUNWsshu, SUNWpl5u, SUNWzoneu, SUNWudaplu, SUNWsshdu, SUNWcsl, SUNWipoib, SUNWcsr, SUNWzfsr, SUNWiopc, SUNWib, SUNWckr, SUNWcakr, SUNWldomr, SUNWcsu, SUNWio-tools, SUNWzfsu, SUNWrcmdc, SUNWsshdr, SUNWsshcu, SUNWcryr, SUNWperl584core, SUNWusb, SUNWefcl, SUNWbtool, SUNWdtrc, SUNWpd, SUNWtoo, SUNWzfskr, SUNWpmr, SUNWmdu, SUNWmdr, SUNWcpcu, SUNWpmu, SUNWust2, SUNWcsd, SUNWvolu, SUNWcry, SUNWarc, SUNWfmdr, SUNWwbsup, SUNWbcp, SUNWs8brandu, SUNWnfsckr, SUNWssad, SUNWnfssu, SUNWnfscr, SUNWtavor, SUNWftdur, SUNWudapltr, SUNWrpcib, SUNWopenssl-libraries, SUNWarcr, SUNWmdb, SUNWigb, SUNWibsdpu, SUNWs9brandr, SUNWust1, SUNWpdu, SUNWs9brandu, SUNWtnfc, SUNWsmapi, SUNWudapltu, SUNWesu, SUNWnfscu, SUNWnxge, SUNWcslr, SUNWintgige, SUNWatfsu, SUNWdmgtu
Patch: 142909-17 Obsoletes: 118814-01, 120038-01, 120816-01, 121128-01, 121394-03, 122085-01, 123194-01, 123271-01, 123332-02, 123334-05, 125022-01, 125108-02, 125174-02, 125200-01, 125201-01, 125808-01, 125896-03, 126308-01, 126428-01, 127723-01, 127759-03, 127762-01, 127882-03, 128032-01, 128324-02, 128346-01, 136891-02, 137017-03, 137028-01, 137123-03, 137133-01, 137291-01, 138046-02, 138081-01, 138098-01, 138112-01, 138116-01, 138118-01, 138120-01, 138157-01, 138169-01, 138223-03, 138263-03, 138283-05, 138318-03, 138324-03, 138375-01, 138381-01, 138411-01, 138627-07, 138644-01, 138764-02, 138848-02, 138858-01, 138870-01, 138872-02, 138874-05, 139390-01, 139468-01, 139487-01, 139503-01, 139504-01, 139508-01, 139509-02, 139514-01, 139553-01, 139568-01, 139935-01, 139941-01, 139943-01, 139945-03, 139946-01, 139948-01, 139949-01, 139958-01, 139970-01, 139971-01, 139975-03, 139983-04, 140003-03, 140078-01, 140144-01, 140146-01, 140151-02, 140157-03, 140165-01, 140167-01, 140169-01, 140175-01, 140192-01, 140386-04, 140391-03, 140395-01, 140397-11, 140401-01, 140413-01, 140557-01, 140559-01, 140562-02, 140681-02, 140788-01, 140917-02, 141012-01, 141022-02, 141026-14, 141030-10, 141034-02, 141054-01, 141536-01, 141542-01, 141544-01, 141550-02, 141562-02, 141723-02, 141740-01, 141773-01, 141780-01, 141899-03, 141906-01, 141914-02, 141922-02, 142005-01, 142055-03, 142236-02, 142242-05, 142245-02, 142247-01, 142249-01, 142257-05, 142259-07, 142263-01, 142290-01, 142330-01, 142346-02, 142390-03, 142436-08, 142481-01, 142528-01, 142539-01, 142541-01, 142675-01, 142900-15, 143051-01, 143052-02, 143054-01, 143117-01, 143119-02, 143120-03, 143122-02, 143125-02, 143128-05, 143131-08, 143135-03, 143137-04, 143350-05, 143352-01, 143354-03, 143356-01, 143357-05, 143359-02, 143360-01, 143515-01, 143519-01, 143521-02, 143523-04, 143528-01, 143556-04, 143558-01, 143565-01, 143569-04, 143574-01, 143576-03, 143583-02, 143585-01, 143586-02, 143590-01, 143595-01, 143597-02, 143603-01, 143605-01, 143607-01, 143611-01, 143613-01, 143623-01, 143895-01, 143897-03, 143899-01, 143903-01, 143905-01, 143907-01, 143909-06, 143911-01, 143920-02, 143927-02, 143933-01, 143935-01, 143943-01, 144015-01, 144017-01, 144019-01, 144021-01, 144023-01, 144043-01, 144045-02, 144049-01, 144051-03, 144056-01, 144110-01, 144182-01, 144258-01, 144369-01, 144373-01, 144389-01, 144453-01, 144494-01, 144511-01, 144624-01, 144761-01, 145024-01, 145049-01, 145051-01, 145102-01, 145103-01 Requires: 118731-01, 118833-36, 118918-24, 119042-09, 119578-30, 120011-14, 120900-04, 121133-02, 121901-01, 126540-02, 126897-02, 127127-11, 127755-01, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142911-01, 142933-02 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWixgbe, SUNWpiclu, SUNWxge, SUNWaccu, SUNWhea, SUNWpapi, SUNWrds, SUNWnfsskr, SUNWmrsas, SUNWudf, SUNWkvm, SUNWmptsas, SUNWrge, SUNWudfr, SUNWpool, SUNWxcu4, SUNWhermon, SUNWfmd, SUNWtftp, SUNWmdbr, SUNWzoneu, SUNWcsl, SUNWipoib, SUNWldomu, SUNWdhcsu, SUNWcsr, SUNWzfsr, SUNWsndmu, SUNWiopc, SUNWib, SUNWckr, SUNWcakr, SUNWcpc, SUNWldomr, SUNWypr, SUNWcsu, SUNWio-tools, SUNWzfsu, SUNWsndmr, SUNWaac, SUNWpsm-lpd, SUNWsacom, SUNWrsgk, SUNWzoner, SUNWses, SUNWusb, SUNWefcl, SUNWnisu, SUNWdtrc, SUNWpd, SUNWppm, SUNWtoo, SUNWzfskr, SUNWniumx, SUNWmdu, SUNWixgb, SUNWmdr, SUNWcpcu, SUNWpmu, SUNWust2, SUNWscpu, SUNWcsd, SUNWpsm-ipp, SUNWcry, SUNWarc, SUNWfmdr, SUNWhxge, SUNWwbsup, SUNWs8brandu, SUNWnfsckr, SUNWssad, SUNWnfssu, SUNWnfscr, SUNWtavor, SUNWftdur, SUNWxcu6, SUNWrpcib, SUNWarcr, SUNWmdb, SUNWigb, SUNWpcu, SUNWs9brandr, SUNWust1, SUNWpdu, SUNWn2cp, SUNWs9brandu, SUNWsmapi, SUNWudapltu, SUNWesu, SUNWnfscu, SUNWnxge, SUNWcslr, SUNWdcar, SUNWippcore, SUNWintgige, SUNWs8brandr, SUNWpsu, SUNWdmgtu
Patch: 144500-19 Obsoletes: 118735-02, 118842-01, 120044-01, 120061-02, 120085-02, 120994-01, 121559-01, 122183-03, 122408-01, 123319-01, 123908-02, 124237-01, 125167-01, 125171-02, 125414-01, 125549-01, 126258-03, 126260-02, 126319-01, 126655-02, 126896-01, 127737-02, 127998-01, 128000-01, 128326-01, 136889-01, 136892-01, 138079-01, 138085-01, 138087-01, 138089-01, 138128-01, 138239-01, 138261-03, 138291-01, 138293-01, 138320-02, 138371-06, 138373-02, 138377-01, 138383-01, 138387-01, 138634-01, 138880-02, 139478-01, 139485-02, 139959-04, 140074-09, 140161-01, 140163-01, 140190-01, 140387-02, 140399-03, 140683-01, 140784-01, 140921-02, 141010-01, 141020-03, 141024-01, 141052-02, 141500-08, 141502-02, 141506-10, 141508-02, 141534-01, 141686-01, 141738-01, 142046-04, 142238-02, 142342-01, 142542-01, 143140-04, 143559-10, 143561-10, 143571-02, 143575-01, 143592-09, 144053-05, 144055-01, 144184-02, 144254-01, 144256-01, 144302-01, 144311-03, 144313-01, 144315-01, 144367-02, 144382-01, 144384-02, 144459-01, 144488-17, 144490-01, 144508-02, 144521-01, 144530-01, 144532-01, 144536-02, 144542-06, 144548-01, 144550-01, 144552-01, 144554-01, 144561-02, 144563-02, 144565-05, 144567-02, 144571-02, 144573-01, 144574-06, 144748-02, 144754-01, 144759-02, 144874-01, 144903-02, 145021-01, 145042-03, 145046-01, 145047-01, 145107-02, 145124-02, 145788-03, 145792-01, 145794-01, 145796-02, 145798-08, 145868-05, 145870-01, 145885-01, 145887-01, 145889-03, 145893-02, 145895-05, 145897-01, 145901-01, 145907-02, 145913-01, 145915-01, 145927-02, 145933-02, 145939-01, 145941-02, 145944-01, 145961-02, 145963-01, 146017-04, 146018-03, 146019-02, 146021-02, 146023-01, 146028-05, 146030-01, 146058-02, 146062-02, 146064-01, 146066-02, 146069-04, 146070-01, 146073-01, 146132-01, 146230-01, 146277-01, 146287-01, 146327-01, 146328-02, 146336-03, 146440-01, 146442-01, 146443-01, 146447-02, 146449-01, 146478-01, 146482-01, 146484-01, 146570-02, 146584-01, 146677-01, 146701-01, 146778-02, 146802-03, 146804-01, 146842-01, 146846-01, 146855-01, 146857-01, 147053-01, 147182-01 Requires: 118833-36, 118918-24, 119042-09, 119254-41, 119578-30, 120011-14, 121901-01, 125891-01, 126897-02, 127127-11, 127755-01, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17, 142933-03, 144526-01, 147061-01 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWixgbe, SUNWbip, SUNWpiclu, SUNWhea, SUNWpapi, SUNWrds, SUNWperl584usr, SUNWnfsskr, SUNWmrsas, SUNWudf, SUNWgss, SUNWosdem, SUNWkvm, SUNWmptsas, SUNWrge, SUNWibsdpib, SUNWudfr, SUNWpool, SUNWfss, SUNWxcu4, SUNWhermon, SUNWiscsitgtu, SUNWfmd, SUNWopenssl-commands, SUNWtsr, SUNWopenssl-include, SUNWmdbr, SUNWsshu, SUNWpl5u, SUNWgssc, SUNWsshdu, SUNWofk, SUNWcsl, SUNWipoib, SUNWypu, SUNWcsr, SUNWzfsr, SUNWsndmu, SUNWkrbr, SUNWib, SUNWckr, SUNWcakr, SUNWkdcu, SUNWkrbu, SUNWldomr, SUNWcsu, SUNWio-tools, SUNWzfsu, SUNWaac, SUNWrcmdc, SUNWsshdr, SUNWsshcu, SUNWpsm-lpd, SUNWtecla, SUNWcryr, SUNWperl584core, SUNWses, SUNWusb, SUNWsmpd, SUNWefcl, SUNWbtool, SUNWnisu, SUNWipplu, SUNWdtrc, SUNWpd, SUNWrdsv3u, SUNWtoo, SUNWzfskr, SUNWrdsv3, SUNWrmwbu, SUNWniumx, SUNWmdu, SUNWixgb, SUNWipfh, SUNWcpcu, SUNWust2, SUNWscpu, SUNWcsd, SUNWvolu, SUNWgssk, SUNWpsm-ipp, SUNWcry, SUNWarc, SUNWdtrp, SUNWscsip, SUNWaudit, SUNWfmdr, SUNWipplr, SUNWhxge, SUNWbcp, SUNWs8brandu, SUNWnfsckr, SUNWcstl, SUNWssad, SUNWnfssu, SUNWnfscr, SUNWtavor, SUNWudapltr, SUNWxcu6, SUNWrpcib, SUNWopenssl-libraries, SUNWarcr, SUNWcar, SUNWmdb, SUNWpcu, SUNWs9brandr, SUNWust1, SUNWpdu, SUNWn2cp, SUNWipfu, SUNWs9brandu, SUNWtnfc, SUNWsmapi, SUNWspnego, SUNWftpu, SUNWrcapu, SUNWudapltu, SUNWesu, SUNWnfscu, SUNWnxge, SUNWcslr, SUNWdcar, SUNWippcore, SUNWintgige, SUNWs8brandr, SUNWatfsu, SUNWpsu, SUNWdmgtu
Patch: 139555-08 Obsoletes: 120062-01, 121130-01, 125551-02, 126264-01, 127743-02, 127853-02, 128253-01, 128296-01, 128318-01, 128322-01, 128340-01, 128406-01, 137095-01, 137106-01, 137278-01, 138058-01, 138106-02, 138114-01, 138231-01, 138241-05, 138397-01, 138639-01, 138850-01, 138864-01, 138878-01, 138888-08, 139385-02, 139458-01, 139459-01, 139466-04, 139483-05, 139489-03, 139492-01, 139494-01, 139498-04, 139500-04, 139502-03, 139506-01, 139551-01, 139558-03, 139560-02, 139562-02, 139566-01, 139570-05, 139571-01, 139572-02, 139574-03, 139579-04, 139931-01, 139936-01, 139938-01, 139939-01, 139942-01, 139947-01, 139951-01, 139952-01, 139960-02, 139965-01, 139994-01, 140000-04, 140076-02, 140077-01, 140142-01, 140173-01, 140194-04, 140196-01, 140197-01, 140334-01, 140389-01, 140402-01, 140411-01, 140677-01, 140679-01, 140774-03, 140776-01, 140794-01, 140855-01, 141006-01, 141008-01 Requires: 125555-02, 118731-01, 118833-36, 118918-24, 119042-09, 119254-41, 119578-30, 120011-14, 120900-04, 121133-02, 126897-02, 127127-11, 127755-01, 137137-09, 138217-01, 140796-01, 140899-01, 141016-01 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWiscsitgtr, SUNWpiclu, SUNWhea, SUNWrds, SUNWncau, SUNWkvm, SUNWibsdpib, SUNWudfr, SUNWpool, SUNWxcu4, SUNWhermon, SUNWiscsitgtu, SUNWfmd, SUNWopenssl-commands, SUNWopenssl-include, SUNWmdbr, SUNWsshu, SUNWpl5u, SUNWzoneu, SUNWudaplu, SUNWsshdu, SUNWcsl, SUNWdhcsu, SUNWcart200, SUNWcsr, SUNWzfsr, SUNWib, SUNWckr, SUNWcakr, SUNWldomr, SUNWcsu, SUNWzfsu, SUNWsshcu, SUNWperl584core, SUNWefcl, SUNWbtool, SUNWdtrc, SUNWpd, SUNWtoo, SUNWzfskr, SUNWmdu, SUNWipfh, SUNWmdr, SUNWcpcu, SUNWust2, SUNWcsd, SUNWcry, SUNWarc, SUNWdtrp, SUNWfmdr, SUNWwbsup, SUNWloc, SUNWnfsckr, SUNWkvmt200, SUNWssad, SUNWnfssu, SUNWtavor, SUNWopenssl-libraries, SUNWarcr, SUNWmdb, SUNWs9brandr, SUNWust1, SUNWpdu, SUNWipfu, SUNWroute, SUNWsmapi, SUNWudapltu, SUNWesu, SUNWnxge, SUNWcslr, SUNWs8brandr, SUNWdmgtu
Patch: 143609-03 Obsoletes: 144196-02 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWiscsitgtr, SUNWcsr
Patch: 145196-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWpiclu
Patch: 145871-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWpiclu
Patch: 145943-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14, 127127-11, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWpiclu
Patch: 145899-06 Obsoletes: 127986-01, 138632-03, 139967-02, 144560-04, 144622-01, 144651-01 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWhea, SUNWcsu, SUNWmdu, SUNWmdr
Patch: 145919-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWhea, SUNWckr
Patch: 146652-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWhea, SUNWckr
Patch: 144558-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 127127-11, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWrds
Patch: 144039-02 Obsoletes: 140961-03, 140964-02 Requires: 119042-09, 120011-14, 121901-01, 123406-02, 126419-02, 139555-08, 140796-01, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWpool, SUNWcsr, SUNWcsu, SUNWzoner
Patch: 146582-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWfmd
Patch: 147440-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 125555-10, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17, 144500-19, 142933-04 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWmdbr, SUNWckr, SUNWcakr
Patch: 144569-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118731-01, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWzoneu
Patch: 145194-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 137137-09, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWzoneu
Patch: 145911-03 Obsoletes: 144556-03 Requires: 120011-14, 120900-04, 121133-02, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWzoneu
Patch: 146334-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14, 121133-02, 127127-11, 139555-08, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWzoneu
Patch: 146767-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14, 121133-02, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWzoneu
Patch: 144540-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118918-24, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsl
Patch: 146654-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsl
Patch: 146656-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsl
Patch: 141900-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 143954-04 Obsoletes: 142053-03, 142485-01, 142487-01, 142535-03 Requires: 127127-11, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr, SUNWcsu, SUNWcslr
Patch: 145019-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 139555-08, 141444-09 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 146476-01 Obsoletes: 144544-01 Requires: 120011-14, 139555-08, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 142332-03 Obsoletes: 142007-01 Requires: 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWckr
Patch: 142394-01 Obsoletes: 141059-01 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWckr
Patch: 144534-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWckr
Patch: 146834-01 Obsoletes: 125911-01, 126262-01 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWckr, SUNWcsu, SUNWs8brandu, SUNWs9brandu
Patch: 143931-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcakr, SUNWcsu
Patch: 141548-01 Obsoletes: 141688-01 Requires: 138217-01, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsu
Patch: 142430-01 Obsoletes: 141936-01 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 139555-08 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsu, SUNWcslr
Patch: 146575-03 Obsoletes: 141590-02, 141765-01, 143941-02 Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWdtrc, SUNWpmu, SUNWdtrp
Patch: 145923-02 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcslr
Patch: 147436-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 120011-14, 127127-11, 137137-09, 139555-08, 141444-09, 142909-17, 144500-19 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcslr

Comment: Post the output of `showrev -p | egrep '139574|139555'`.  It appears Sun patched this back in 2009.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33100

Comment: Output of the command added. Looks like the OS has the patches.

Comment: I've tried to build on Solaris 11 and got the following error (when building libstdc++ lib):   ld.so.1: perl: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/perl5/5.12/bin/perl: symbol PL_exit_flags: referenced symbol not found